# Bigger document icons in search results (SharePoint 2010)

Tags: sharepoint, search, xslt, sharepoint-2010, icons

So i'm configuring my custom core results web part for document search and I need to display bigger document icons, like [image] instead of [image] for all document types.

I found out that this part in xsl describes the icon:

```
<div class="srch-Icon" id="{concat($currentId,'_Icon')}">                       
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="isdocument='True'">
            <a>
                <xsl:attribute name="href">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('/_layouts/SPDocRedirect/SPItemRedirect.aspx?Type=filterid&amp;ItemId=',$listitemid,'&amp;Url=', url)"/>
                  </xsl:attribute>
                  <xsl:attribute name="title">
                    <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                  </xsl:attribute>
                  <img align="absmiddle" src="{imageurl}" border="0" alt="{imageurl/@imageurldescription}" />   
            </a>
        </xsl:when>      
    </xsl:choose>           
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="isdocument='False'">                
              <img align="absmiddle" src="{imageurl}" border="0" alt="{imageurl/@imageurldescription}" />   
        </xsl:when>      
    </xsl:choose>
```

Can anyone suggest what should I edit in  the above xsl? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like Matthew's answer, but if you don't like the icons being too small.  Consider this trick.

Update your XSLT to include a class name (swapicon) on the img tags, like so:

```
<img class="swapicon" align="absmiddle" src="{imageurl}" border="0" alt="{imageurl/@imageurldescription}" />
```

These icons are located in the hive, _layouts folder.  You need to make new higher res icons for all the file formats, with the exact same filenames.  Then store them in a picture library.  Use JQuery onload(), inserted into the search results page, to search for that class name and replace the img href from the hive URL:

```
http://servername/_layouts/images/
```

to your picture library URL:

```
http://servername/fileformaticons/
```

So the images on the search results page will have a URL that looks like:

```
http://servername/fileformaticons/adobe.png
```

The only problem, is there will be a flicker of the images after the page loads to render the new icons, and it will slow down the page load.  It's just a client-side way of solving it.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer :) I've already solved this problem, a similar way like you suggested. I've downloaded bigger icons for document types and placed them in the hive with old ones adding `_big` to the title, and in the xslt, I've just added a rule that if it's document, it adds `_big` to the href of the icon. Works great! :)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is more a question about HTML/CSS.

Assuming the `<img>` tags in your example are the icons you can either update your image tag to include a width or height:

```
<img style="height:100px;" align="absmiddle" src="{imageurl}" border="0" alt="{imageurl/@imageurldescription}" />
```

Or update the CSS to target your images contained within the `srch-icon` class:

```
.srch-icon img {
  height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know, but those icons are small-sized by themselves, so they just stretch and the view is horrible, I've just downloaded bigger images and replaced the old ones in the 14 hive :)